# Cannot read data from Kafka partition on exact listener port

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I have Kafka cluster of 3 nodes. I am using **kafkacat** to list data from Kafka. I configure **PLAINTEXT** and **VPN_PLAINTEXT** listeners:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:6667,VPN_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:6669
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://hadoop-kafka1-stg.local.company.cloud:6667,VPN_PLAINTEXT://hadoop-kafka1-stg-vip.local.company.cloud:6669
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,VPN_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
```

We find out, we cannot consume data from node 1 (only) - from topics where partition leader is node 1 with error:

```
kafkacat -C -b hadoop-kafka1-stg-vip.local.company.cloud:6669 -t <topic-name> -o beginning -e -q -p 11
% ERROR: Topic <topic-name> [11] error: Broker: Not leader for partition
```

I can see, node 1 is leader for this partition:

```
Metadata for <topic-name> (from broker 3: hadoop-kafka3-stg-vip.local.company.cloud:6669/3):
 3 brokers:
  broker 2 at hadoop-kafka2-stg-vip.local.company.cloud:6669
  broker 3 at hadoop-kafka3-stg-vip.local.company.cloud:6669 (controller)
  broker 1 at hadoop-kafka1-stg-vip.local.company.cloud:6669
 1 topics:
  topic "<topic-name>" with 12 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 2, replicas: 2,1,3, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 1, leader 3, replicas: 3,2,1, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 2, leader 1, replicas: 1,3,2, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 3, leader 2, replicas: 2,3,1, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 4, leader 3, replicas: 3,1,2, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 5, leader 1, replicas: 1,2,3, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 6, leader 2, replicas: 2,1,3, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 7, leader 3, replicas: 3,2,1, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 8, leader 1, replicas: 1,3,2, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 9, leader 2, replicas: 2,3,1, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 10, leader 3, replicas: 3,1,2, isrs: 3,2,1
    partition 11, leader 1, replicas: 1,2,3, isrs: 3,2,1
```

I thought the data on node could be corrupted, so I remove everything from data directory `kafka_data_dir` for Kafka. When I start the daemon, I could see it syncing. After that, the issue persists. There is nothing suspicious in logs.

Could anybody describ and help to find out where is the root cause? Only node number 1 encounter this issue. When I ask the same node on port **6667**, it works smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried providing all the brokers or one of the others as your bootstrap? It doesn't matter who the leader is for the CLI command. That being said, something with your VPN is likely stopping the traffic

Comment: It does not matter which node I ask. When I ask node 1 for partition which leader is node 2 or 3, it works. That means, the first messages between kafkacat and kafka node 1 works fine. The pattern that does not work is when kafka node 1 is leader of partition I asked for

Comment: If you force kafka1 to become the controller, then what happens?

Answer (score 0):

After deeper investigation of traffic with tcpdump I find out that the Kafka configuration was without any problem. When I asked **node1** for topic partition, tcpdump on **node1** did not catch any packets. Requests has been sent to **node3**. Requests should be forwarded based on DNS to the right Kafka nodes over Citrix, but the configuration was wrong:

- hadoop-kafka1-stg-vip.local.company.cloud -> node 3
- hadoop-kafka2-stg-vip.local.company.cloud -> node 2
- hadoop-kafka3-stg-vip.local.company.cloud -> node 3

That's the reason, why requests for partition where **node1** is not leader works, and when asked for partition where **node1** was leader failed with message `Broker: Not leader for partition` because it was always forwared to **node3** by Citrix.